# Determine if Moment.js input specified a UTC offset

Tags: javascript, momentjs

Consider the following date/time inputs:

- 2020-05-28T02:54:09
- 2020-05-28T02:54:09+03:00

Is there a way in Moment.js to determine if the input is local or not? In other words, is there a way to determine if a UTC offset was specified or not?

From the [documentation](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/) it is understood that `moment(...)` treats all times as local, and `moment.parseZone(...)` keep the input zone passed in. Because I need to keep the offset when it is specified, I use `moment.parseZone(...)`. Unfortunately, when the input does not have an offset specified, `moment.parseZone(...).utcOffset()` returns `0` and `moment.parseZone(...).isLocal()` returns `false`. I created an [issue](https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/5569) on the GitHub repository for this behavior since I believe this is a bug.

With this (current) limitation in mind, is there an alternative approach to determine with Moment.js if the input string contains an offset? I prefer to not perform manual string checking since the string may be provided to me in a format that's customized by the user:

```js
function myFunction(dateTimeInput, format) {
  const m = moment.parseZone(dateTimeInput, format);
  // did user provide a `dateTimeInput` with an offset?
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I got here from your issue on github.

I also believe that the moment's behavior is not consistent with its 
 documentation in regards to parseZone.

While I'm waiting on confirmation for the intended behavior, you might be able to test your user's input against:

```
/Z|[+-]\d\d:?\d\d/i
```

which is also moment's internal method of finding offset from input string, in order to know whether your user provided an offset.

Note: the above code does not support short offsets